# Apache returns 403 on domain without www prefix

Tags: apache-2.4

My web returns a 403 on www.example.com, but works ok on [name].com. In my apache2.conf file, I have ServerName=www.example.com, as well as in the VirtualHost tag, but there I have ServerAlias=example.com as well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
...
```

When I run /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S, I get:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.example.com.conf:1)
                 alias example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

What I want is for www.example.com and example.com to point to the same service. Now it seems that it's using the default conf file when the www prefix is used.

Comment: Can you post your virtual host file instead ? Thanks (:

Comment: I "solved" this by setting ServerName haha.com in the main apache2.conf file. Would have liked to fix it properly, though...

Comment: Set the ServerName as a default name like localhost so it does not interfere with your virtual host www.[name].com.

Comment: Btw, it should be ServerName domain.tld; ServerAlias sub.domain.tld, try to dissite your default conf and set a proper one for your service.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is looking for the answer, using the comments under the question, I set the ServerName in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to localhost.

That, coupled with a correct VirtualHost and htaccess redirect, every "version" of my domain goes to the same one.

Thanks to erikwkolstad and DeadEye for the pointers.